# Send response before query is complete

Tags: sql-server, node.js

I have a web app that calls queries to SQL Server via Node.js.

I want to fire off a query from the client that usually takes 1 - 2 seconds, however in some special cases may take up to a minute and a half.

The client wants a response to the XHR request, and doesn't want to wait a minute and a half. It doesn't care what the response says.

The query is a delete statement via openquery - it isn't expecting results back.

Is there any way to fire such a thing as a delete statement and then return a response to the query before it is complete, regardless of the results? I haven't heard of such a thing so I don't know where to look, but can't find it so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In many other languages the answer would involve threading but since js does not support threads you have to work with processes to create asynch returns like the one you describe.

In your app you would [spawn a child process](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) from the REST/Web API  function that was  called and which is responsible for returning a result to the client. This scheme would decouple your dependency on the execution time of the delete query. Whether the child process runs in 2 seconds or 2 minutes your client would not know the difference, just as he/she wants it, and the result would seem almost immediate.

There are a number of simple samples and other resources like [this one](http://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/child-processes/how-to-spawn-a-child-process) and [this one](http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/Nodejs-managing-child-processes-starting-stopping-exec-spawn) etc. available.

Simple code sample for running child processes from Nodejs:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('node -v', function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
    console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
    if (error !== null) {
        console.log('exec error: ' + error);
    }
 });
```

You probably don't care or even need the in/out/error streams so your code might look even simpler. Something like this:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('node -v', function() {
    // put your delete code here
 });
```

*This section added and modified from comments below:*

The only way I know of launching an async task in SQL Server is to schedule the execution of a query, sproc etc. But that's an ugly hack. There are native APIs that allow you to do it programmatically from a client but you're back to where you started.

In any case , I would suggest not implementing this feature in SQL because of the tight coupling you would create between the UI/UX and the back end. And I don't think a deep dive   into node.js is necessary to implement the child process solution. It's pretty straightforward, especially if you don't care about the result. Simple fire and forget.

Comment: Okay thank you. That is informative. Does this mean, though, that it isn't possible to do it at the SQL level? I didn't want to dive into my Node.js to handle it.

Comment: @dc2: The only way I know of launching an async task in SQL Server is to schedule the execution of a query, sproc etc. But that's an ugly hack. There are native APIs that allow you to do it programmatically from a client but you're back to where you started. In any case though, I would suggest not implementing this feature in SQL because of the tight coupling you would create between the UI/UX and the back end. And I'm not sure how deep you'd have to dive into node.js to do the process thing. It's pretty straightforward, especially if you don't care about the result. Simple fire and forget.

Comment: Yeah, i'll probably throw a param into my REST request that states "don't wait for a response". That should be fairly simple. Definitely not doing the job schedule hack!